# jQuery FullCalendar: Can I highlight some time ranges so that users know they are selectable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have an application in which the selectable time ranges are variable. That is, in the week view, for monday I may want the user to only be able to select times from 12:00 to 14:00h. On thursday only from 17:00h to 19:00h and so forth.

I know I can handle the `select` event to constrain the user but I would like to present a visual indication of that time ranges are selectable. I also know I can use `minTime` and `maxTime` to limit the time tables but I need the `weekView`, in which time ranges are variable.

I searched the documentation and the web and found nothing.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

The weekView (as opposed to the agendaWeek) has no grid of times, so how would you choose where to display the time ranges?

If you mean the agendaWeek the structure of the HTML makes what you want to do very difficult as essentially its made of two superimposed tables, one with the columns and another with the rows (for the different time blocks of half hour or whatever).  The only way to do what you want would be to superimpose divs of the right size on top of that matrix.  I can give you some hints if you want to attempt that!

Comment: thank you so much for your feedback. In fact I meant agendaWeek, sorry. Mm.. that sounds an overkill to me now. I'm thinking on an alternative solution: My software works with both agendaWeek and agendaDay. If I can't highlight wich time ranges are available in the agendaWeek, can I change the minTime and maxTime in the agendaDay as the user navigates through the calendar?

Comment: You'd need to rebuild the calendar HTML every time you changed the minTime and maxTime - that's not so bad if you want to do it when the user changes the date range.  If you want to do it that way let me know I'll help you if pos.

Comment: Were you able to find any solution for this? I'm facing a similar issue 2 years later. Min and Max time don't accept array. I want to make Monday 9am - 12pm, Tuesday 10am - 2pm, Wed 4pm-pm as highlighted. Which doesn't seem to be possible at the moment. Unfortunately there's no other calendar of the level of FullCalendar :(